# A better way to call static methods in user-submitted code?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a large data set. I am creating a system which allows users to submit java source files, which will then be applied to the data set. To be more specific, each submitted java source file must contain a static method with a specific name, let's say toBeInvoked(). toBeInvoked will take a row of the data set as an array parameter. I want to call the toBeInvoked method of each submitted source file on each row in the data set. I also need to implement security measures (so toBeInvoked() can't do I/O, can't call exit, etc.).

Currently, my implementation is this: I have a list of the names of the java source files. For each file, I create an instance of the custom secure ClassLoader which I coded, which compiles the source file and returns the compiled class. I use reflection to extract the static method toBeInvoked() (e.g. method = c.getMethod("toBeInvoked", double[].class)). Then, I iterate over the rows of the data set, and invoke the method on each row.

There are at least two problems with my approach:

- it appears to be painfully slow (I've heard reflection tends to be slow)
- the code is more complicated than I would like

Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: The expensive thing here is most likely not the reflective call (unless it's really called *very* often), but the compilation! How are you compiling this? Using the built-in `JavaCompiler` class, or via some external `Runtime.exec` call?` In any case, apart from the compilation, the functionality of "Plug-Ins" can usually be achieved with a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html , although it's not entirely clear whether this is applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no significantly better approach given the constraints that you have set yourself.

For what it is worth, what makes this "painfully slow" is compiling the source files to class files and loading them.  That is many orders of magnitude slower than the use of reflection to call the methods.

(Use of a common interface rather than static methods is not going to make a measurable difference to speed, and the reduction in complexity is relatively small.)

If you really want to simplify this and speed it up, change your architecture so that the code is provided as a JAR file containing all of the compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your #toBeInvoked() could be defined in an interface rather than being static (it should be!), you could just load the class and cast it to the interface:

```
Class<? extends YourInterface> c = Class.forName("name", true, classLoader).asSubclass(YourInterface.class);
YourInterface i = c.newInstance();
```

Afterwards invoke #toBeInvoked() directly.

Also have a look into java.util.ServiceLoader, which could be helpful for finding the right class to load in case you have more than one source file.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use an interface.  This will allow you to have multiple instance with their own state (useful for multi-threading) but more importantly you can use an interface, first to define which methods must be implemented but also to call the methods.

Reflection is slow but this is only relative to other options such as a direct method call.  If you are scanning a large data set, the fact you have to pulling data from main memory is likely to be much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following steps for your problem.

1. To check if the method contains any unwanted code, you need to have a check script which can do these checks at upload time.
2. Create an Interface having a method toBeInvoked() (not a static method).
3. All the classes which are uploaded must implement this interface and add the logic inside this method.
4. you can have your custom class loader scan a particular folder for new classes being added and load them accordingly.
5. When a file is uploaded and successfully validated, you can compile and copy the class file to the folder which class loader scans.
6. You processor class can lookup for new files and then call toBeInvoked() method on loaded class when required.

Hope this help. (Note that i have used a similar mechanism to load dynamically workflow step classes in Workflow Engine tool which was developed).